# Convergence in distribution of BM started in (x,y) to BM started in (0,0)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B$
  be a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
 . Let $\mathbb{P}_{(x,y)}$
  denote a probability measure under which $B$
  is started at $(x,y)$
 . Is it true in general that, for measurable set $A$,

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\mathbb{P}_{(x,y)}((B_{t})_{t\geq0}\in A)=\mathbb{P}_{(0,0)}((B_{t})_{t\geq0}\in A)$?

I feel like this is just convergence in distribution but Im very uncertain if it is correct or not.

If it is indeed true, is it then part of a more general fact? E.g. is it always true for general stochastic processes. Or is it related to a general theorem or form of convergence?

I'd be extremely grateful for any inputs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Trivially, since if $B$ is a Brownian motion starting from $(0,0)$, then $B^{x,y}:=B+(x,y)$ is a Brownian motion starting from $(x,y)$, and $B^{x,y}\to B$ almost surely when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.